# Import after export all data in OFBiz

Tags: ofbiz

After setup for new ecommerce business, I would like to export all data, and stored as seed-ext data.

Now, I setup new ofbiz instance, and run ant task `load-extseed` to load previous ext seed data, but many errors occured which caused by key in database.

My question is "Is there any ways to import data after export all data"?

Thank for any comments, ideas or answers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve FK errors in loaded data you have a couple options:

1. change the files to reorder the data to satisfy dependencies
2. use the dummy FKs option Bilgin mentioned

The dummy FKs option can also be done on the command line with "createfks=true". If you are using the ant target you may need to modify it to add this argument.

Comment: `1` option is the way i have done, thank you, welcome @David E. Jones to stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try importing the data from webtools data import page.
Use "Create Dummy FKs" option

Comment: I would just like to import from ant via `load-extseed`, don't via import function in webtools data import page.

Comment: Thank for your answer, if you have another solutions, please suggest me :-)